# MySQL Minus query syntax

Tags: mysql

I am working on a query that will pull information from one part of the database but remove a part of the result.  This is the database:

```
CREATE TABLE elements 
(
   atomicNumber INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   symbol VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
   elementName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
);    

INSERT INTO elements VALUES (1, 'H', 'Hydrogen');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES (2, 'He', 'Helium');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES (3, 'Li', 'Lithium'); 
INSERT INTO elements VALUES (4, 'Be', 'Beryllium');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES (5, 'B', 'Boron');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES (6, 'C', 'Carbon');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES (7, 'N', 'Nitrogen');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES (8, 'O', 'Oxygen');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES (9, 'F', 'Fluorine');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES (10, 'Ne', 'Neon');
```

I want to return all the records in the database other than atomicNumber 1.  This is the query I use:

```
Select atomicNumber, symbol, elementName From elements Minus select atomicNumber, symbol, elementName Where atomicNumber = 1;
```

When I do that query, I get this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Minus....
```

What is my error in the query syntax?  I have looked around for the last few hours but cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why do you have the word `Minus` in there?  What are you trying to do?  Where did you see the syntax `SELECT ... FROM ... Minus SELECT ... WHERE ...`?  That makes no sense.  Queries are `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...`.

Comment: Mysql doesn't support minus syntax, use a not exists instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128844/minus-operator-giving-me-erros-in-mysql though I don't know why you wouldn't juse use atomicNumber != 1 or not in (1) if you have a set.

Comment: "can't find out what's wrong?" It tells you right in the error message!

Comment: I am teaching myself mySQL and I couldn't figure out what was wrong.  The fact that mysql doesn't support MINUS was something I hadn't gotten to in the book.  Basically, my query was soemthing like this:

Comment: Select atomicNumber, symbol, elementName, groupNumber From elements where groupNumber = 1 AND atomicNumber !=1;

Comment: @SteveFarmer: I've never heard of the `MINUS` statement before.  What databases support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude different elements, you can just use the not-equals comparison:

```
SELECT * FROM elements WHERE atomicNumber != 1;
```

If you have many elements that you'd like to exclude, you can use NOT IN instead (but it may not be very performant):

```
SELECT * FROM elements WHERE atomicNumber NOT IN (2,5,10);
```

- [Reference on SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)
- [Reference on using different predicates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/expressions.html)

Comment: Thank you!  My database was a bit more than what I posted here (included groups, periods) but that was enough for me to find the correct answer.  :)

Answer (score 0):

From? on the second query

```
Select atomicNumber, symbol, elementName From elements Minus select atomicNumber, symbol, elementName Where atomicNumber = 1;

Select atomicNumber, symbol, elementName FROM elements Where atomicNumber = 1;
```

I guess..

I mean, you are missing a From statement, just that, review your code.